# Check for ranges in Systemverilog with least synthesis area

Tags: range, verilog, system-verilog, comparator

I have various inputs that vary in width. I have to detect if each input falls within some specific ranges. For example, an input may be 6 bits and hence in theory have values of 0-63. However, I want to check if it happens to be 2-5, 8, 14-50, 52, 54, 56-58, 61-63. Is there any method that is more area-efficient for synthesis than doing straight-up range or equal comparisons? Currently I would have:

```
always_comb begin
   value_is_in_special_range = 1'b0;
   if (
      (value >= 'd2 && value <= 'd5) ||
      (value == 'd8) ||
      (value >= 'd14 && value <= 'd50) ||
      (value == 'd52) ||
      (value == 'd54) ||
      (value >= 'd56 && value <= 'd58) ||
      (value >= 'd61 && value <= 'd63) ||
   ) begin
      value_is_in_special_range = 1'b1;
   end
end
```

The specific ranges for various inputs are quite random and could fall nicely within relatively few large ranges, or they could be scattered all over the place.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to put this code into the synthesis tool and optimization should take care of sharing common sub expressions to make all these comparisons most efficient. This assumes all the values and ranges you want comparisons to are constants.

BTW, a simpler way of writing this expression in SystemVerilog is using the set membership operator:

```
assign value_is_in_special_range = 
    value inside {[2:5], 8, [14:50], 52, 54, [56:58], [61:63]};
```